# Determine independence of functions of r.v.'s and compute joint distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-theory, bayesian

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ be independent and $\operatorname{Exp}( \lambda )$. We have,
$$Y_1 := X_1+X_2+ X_3+ X_4$$
$$Y_2:= \frac{X_1 }{X_1+X_2}$$
$$Y_3:= \frac{X_1 + X_2 }{X_1+X_2+ X_3}$$
$$Y_4:=\frac{X_1 + X_2 + X_3}{X_1+X_2+ X_3+ X_4}$$
We are now supposed to show that these, $Y_i$ are independent and determine their joint distribution (of $(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4)$). 
 
My initial approach is to use the fact that,
$$Y_i = g_i(X_1,\dots,X_n)$$
$$X_i = h_i(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$$
$$f_\mathbf{Y}(y_1,\dots,y_n) = f_\mathbf{X}(h_1(y_1,\dots,y_n),\dots,h_n(y_1,\dots,y_n)) \cdot |J|$$
$J$ being the Jacobian determinant. I start of with re-writing each $X_i$ as a function of $(Y_1,\dots, Y_1)$ and get, after some manipulations that,
$$X_1 = Y_1 Y_2 Y_3 Y_4$$
$$X_2 = Y_1 Y_3 Y_4 (1-Y_2)$$
$$X_3 = Y_1 Y_4(1-Y_3)$$
$$X_4 = Y_1(1-Y_4)$$

Computing all partial derivatives,$\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_i}$ , yields me the following matrix,

\begin{bmatrix}
y_2y_3y_4     & y_1y_3y_4  & y_1y_2y_4     & y_1y_2y_3 \\ 
y_3y_4(1-y_2) & -y_1y_3y_4 & y_1y_4(1-y_2) & y_1y_3(1-y_2) \\ 
y_4(1-y_3)    & 0          & -y_1y_4       & y_1(1-y_3) \\ 
1-y_4         & 0          & 0             & -y_1 
\end{bmatrix}

My linear algebra is a little rusty, but I believe the doing the following is valid. The aim is to perform row/column operations to obtain a triangular determinant. First I swap the columns: 1. Swap column #1 and #4. 2. Swap column #2 and #1, 3. Swap column #2 and #3. This yields

\begin{bmatrix}
 y_1y_3y_4  & y_1y_2y_4     & y_1y_2y_3    &  y_2y_3y_4      \\ 
 -y_1y_3y_4 & y_1y_4(1-y_2) & y_1y_3(1-y_2)& y_3y_4(1-y_2) \\ 
 0          & -y_1y_4       & y_1(1-y_3)   &  y_4(1-y_3)   \\ 
 0          & 0             & -y_1         & 1-y_4
\end{bmatrix}

I then: 
1. Add row #1 to row #2. 2. Add row #2 to row #3. 3. Add row #3 to row #4.
I then have,

\begin{bmatrix}
y_1y_3y_4     & y_1y_2y_4  & y_1y_2y_3     & y_2y_3y_4\\ 
0             & y_1y_4     & y_1y_3        & y_3y_4 \\ 
0             & 0          & y_1           & y_4 \\ 
0             & 0          & 0             &  1
\end{bmatrix}
If I've done this correctly then,
$$
|J| = y_1^3 y_4^2 y_3
$$
We have that the joint p.d.f of $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ is,
$$
f_\mathbf{X} = \lambda^4 e^{-\lambda(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)}
$$
We then get, after some manipulation $(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = y_1)$, that,
$$
f_\mathbf{Y} = \lambda^4 e^{-\lambda y_1} y_1^3 y_4^2 y_3 $$

 
The question is now, have I done this correctly (i.e. computed the joint distribution of $(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4)$? If so, how do I show independence for the $Y_i$'s? Do I have to compute all the marginal distributions or is there a simpler approach?

Any hints on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: looks ok (to me), you might write supports of $y_1,\dots,y_4$.

Comment: I think it's OK, too.  You might offer, as a check, that the integral of your joint density over the range in question works out to 1.

Comment: So you have $y_1\ge0,\  0\le y_2\le 1,\  0 \le y_3\le 1,\  0\le y_4\le 1.$ I wouldn't omit that from any write-up explaining the solution. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you!! I integrated all $y_i$ over $[ 0; \inf [$ and couldn't get the product to equal one. This solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you've done is correct (I haven't checked the details), then independence of $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4$ follows from the factorization of their joint density: It's the product of a function of $y_1,$ a function of $y_2,$ a function of $y_3,$ and a function of $y_4.$ That's enough to infer independence. (If it depended on something like $y_2^2+y_2^2$ or $\cos(y_1+y_2),$ etc., then it would not be such a product. The function of $y_2$ in this case is constant, and from that you conclude that $Y_2$ is uniformly distributed.